# Incorrect from name encoding characters with MailAdress

Tags: .net, encoding

I am having an issue with the encoding of a string used as the "FromName"  properties of the MailAdress in .Net.

The ó in the fromName seems to be encoded with UTF-8 (see below). The thing is that according to the .Net documentation the FromName is supposed to be either encoded in ASCII (which supports the ó) or if any issues with  iso-8859-1 character set (which included this char too).

But when i check the headers of the email I sent with that name, the from contains this string :

```
=?utf-8?Q?S=C3=B3nia,balba?=
<Sonia.balba@example.com>
```

This is interpreted as is by outlook, and as a result those weird chars appears as the sender of the mail instead of

```
Sónia,balba 
<Sonia.balba@example.com>
```

I did not find any way to indicate which charset to use.

Is there anyway to actually have the correct encoding in this part of the email header ?

Comment: What do you mean by "either encoded in ASCII (which supports the ó)"? ASCII itself does *not* include ó.

Comment: Well, the extended ASCII table does... and what I meant is cf MSDN documentation : "If displayName contains non-ASCII characters, the iso-8859-1 character set is used for the displayName encoding."

Comment: "Extended ASCII" != "ASCII". ASCII is a well-defined term, and it doesn't include any accented characters. "Extended ASCII" is a horrible term which covers a wide range of encodings. Avoid it if you possibly can. It seems odd that it's using UTF-8 instead of ISO-8859-1 - or rather, it seems odd to me that it would be documented to use ISO-8859-1 to start with. I suspect the docs are out of date. However, it looks like it's a reasonable encoding of Sónia,balba to me.

Comment: If you want to specify ISO-8859-1, you can use the constructor which takes an `Encoding` as well...

Comment: Did not really worked out ! I tryed to force the ISO-8859-1 in the constructor, the result is different : "=?iso-8859-1?Q?S=F3nia,_balba?=" . I think I'm gonna simply strip the accented chars that seems not to be supported...